# Information on the number of rides - UBER

Tags: uber-api

I am trying to understand how many rides are created by Uber in a city. Idea is look at the employment generated by Uber. Is there a way to get such information from API's

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not currently possible to do this with the API.

Comment: This answer would be better-suited as a comment citing a primary source.

Comment: @DustinWhittle thanks for the information. What about other online platforms like TaskRabbit, Amazon Mturks